# GPIO pin wiring for LEDs and their resistors

Tags: gpio, led, wiring, pi-a

I have a Raspberry Pi 1 Model A and am trying to control an LED from an app that I will be running on it. The wiring I'm planning on going with is:

[image]

Even though thats a RPI 3 in the diagram above, the concept is the same:

1. Connect the RPi to a suitable power source (via Micro USB)
2. Connect the 3.3V pin on the RPi to the power rail on the breadboard
3. Connect the column where the **LED (1.2V @ 100mA)** will be placed to power through a **resistor (47 ohm)**
4. Then just connect the column where the LED's 2nd leg is located back to a GPIO pin that is configured to be an **output pin**

So I wanted to verify (I'm afraid I'm going to fry my pi!):

- That the wiring is correct; and
- That I'm using the correct resistor to do the job (R = V/I = (3.3V - 1.2V)/.1A = 2.1V / .1A = 21 ohms...so I figured 47 ohms is OK); and
- That I should be configuring my GPIO pin to be on **output** pin afterall

Thanks!

Comment: A LED that is 1.2V/100mA, is it a special one, high intensity? Typical values I have seen is more in the range 1,8V/20mA for red LED's.

Comment: Hi @MatsK (+1) it might be...its all they had at my local RadioShack though. Will my resistor be enough for it? Is it somehow incompatible with the RPi? Or am I fine?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why won't the LED turn on?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/72374/why-wont-the-led-turn-on)

Comment: Phrasing of the question is not identical to the duplicate, but the answers are directly relevant.

Comment: I haven't even gotten to the point where I can confirm the LED will/won't turn off Brick...I'm asking for confirmation/clarification of my setup/design!

Comment: The Raspberry Pi's GPIO can drive 16mA and 100mA is far above that! And please use U for voltage, V is for Velocity ;-) And if you do recalculate you will get a R = 75-100 ohm.

Comment: Thanks @MatsK (+1): How is my calculation off? 2.1 / .1 = 21 ohms, no? Can you show me specifically where I'm miscalculating? Also lets pretend I fix the LED and resistor being used...how does my diagram look? Thanks again!

Comment: http://led.linear1.org/1led.wiz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some considerations:

- A maximum of 16mA per GPIO with the total current from all GPIOs not exceeding 50mA.
- Calculate the resistance, its the limiter for the current.

  Normal data for a red LED: ~1.8 volt, 16mAmpere (0,016A)

  U = 3.3V - 1.8V = 1.5V

  R = U / I

  1.5V/0.016A = 94 ohm

And regarding the schematic, this is working, your a bit turned around. [image]

Comment: Thanks @MatsK (+1) - but where are you getting 1.8V and .02A from?! My LED is 1.2V at .1A. Thanks for any clarification there (also thanks for clearing up the wiring with your diagram, that helps enormously!).

Comment: You cant use that LED ! 100mA is more than the 16mA that the GPIO can be loaded with!!!!! And that I have stated several times!!!!! So buy a LED that is approx in the 16mA range.

Comment: Oh I can read what you've wrote perfectly fine! You've told me (like you said) several times that I can't use this LED. But you are confusing me because you're using an example that uses a 1.8V LED rated at .02A, and I'm not sure where that's coming from. Is that just an example you're providing here?

Comment: Sorry for being annoyed. Here is some quite common values for LED that will shed some light over the issue: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d6/Karakteristikat_e_LED_diodave.gif

Comment: OK, I *think* what you're trying to say is that **if** I had a 1.8V LED rated at 20mA, then I would need 3.3V - 1.8V / .02A = 75 ohm. If that's the case, and you're just citing this as an example, then I follow you 100%.

Comment: Bulls eye :-) So now you have to buy a LED that is suitable for your Raspberry Pi.

Comment: It would not hurt to try the LED w/ 16-20 mA.  LEDs simply get dimmer with less current, but it might well be bright enough.  I'm dubious an "only one I could find at Radio Shack" LED is rated at 100 mA.  Note that they will burn out if you overcurrent them.

Comment: If the maximum current of 16mA can be drawn from a GPIO pin then shouldn’t the resistance value be 1.5V/0.016A = 94ohm?

Comment: True!, thanx @UdayHiwarale